# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1. When install geopandas

Tags: python, python-module

I'm using win10 and trying to install geopandas:

```
C:\Users\61432>pip install geopandas

Collecting geopandas
  Using cached geopandas-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (928 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: shapely in c:\users\61432\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geopandas) (1.7.0)
Collecting fiona
  Using cached Fiona-1.8.13.post1.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\61432\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\61432\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xgic7o3y\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\61432\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xgic7o3y\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\61432\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xgic7o3y\fiona\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\61432\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xgic7o3y\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: An internet search of the GDAL API error string would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Download packages from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
   (GDAL,FIONA) put in the file_path where you're working the project
2. Second Install the packages
   cd the file_path> pip install GDAL
   i.e (data) C:\Users\mourinho\project> pip install GDAL-3.2.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
   then
   pip install Fiona
   i.e (data) C:\Users\mourinho\project> pip install Fiona-1.8.18-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
3. pip install geopandas